# How to handle dates on Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

From what I understand, when you store a date:

```
const date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

You are storing a date object in the local timezone. However, when I later read this date from Firestore using:

```
doc.data().date.toDate()
```

This gives me the date in UTC, instead of the local timezone. Is this the expected behaviour? Am I understanding this correctly? It seems like it would make more sense to retrieve the date in local time since the date you stored is in local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you store a date (in Firestore) with
> `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())`, you are storing a
> date object in the local timezone.

This is actually not correct: All timestamps in Firestore are saved **in UTC**. The timezone of the user who saved the timestamp is not saved with the timestamp value.

> Is this the expected behaviour?

Yes, storing the value in UTC gives the maximum flexibility for the developer to display it as desired, depending on his specific requirements.

As a matter of fact, it's up to the developer to display it with the timezone he wants when displaying it in a frontend. For example, the Firebase console converts the UTC date the timezone to which your computer is configured.